# Trigger materialize.css toast on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I'm trying to trigger a toast when the the page load using materialize.css and jquery, but it's now working, here my code:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 4000);
    });
</script>
```

This code is inside head tags.

Comment: Please add also the javascript code you are using to trigger the toast (Ej. `Materialize.toast(...)`

Comment: sorry, didn't get pasted. fixed

Comment: You also don't seem to have the `materialize.js` script added to your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're missing Materialize js file. For me, your code is properly working.

Just add this to your head as well.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.js"></script>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/ZpgYGQ)

Comment: have it at the end of the body <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.js"></script>

Comment: That'll work as well - Even better! Generally, file imports should always happen at the end of your body. Just mentioned your `<head>` tag to avoid possible complications, since you used your `<script>` in your `<head>`as well.

Comment: have moved this script at the end of the body just next to the script links and now seems working. Thanks @Aer0

Comment: You're welcome! Would be nice if you could accept my answer though. :)